# Some map tiles not rendering in mobile layout

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map rendered in a page using the V3 maps api. Everything works great, but for some reason, the map tiles in the initial view are not rendering in the mobile view. It breaks at the 580px breakpoint, but I can't find anything in my css that seems like it would cause the problem. I do go from fixed dimensions to percentages on the map container, but I have tried it with fixed dimensions all the time and it does not fix the problem. Page is here: https://www.edenrift.com/Taste.

Note that if you pan the map to see the area to the left of the initial view, you can see that tiles are rendering, just not the ones in the initial view. Also note how the zoom buttons also get messed up at the same breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking questions here, you are asked to provide **all necessary code to reproduce the issue**. Not a link to your live code as this is not useful to other readers once your code has changed or the URL is not valid anymore.

That said, the following rule is causing your issue:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) img {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: none;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
}
```

And more specifically the `max-width: 100% !important;`

It's obvious it's a CSS issue as even the map controls are messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I know I'm supposed to post code, but even I couldn't reproduce the issue when placing the same code on a new page in my dev environment. I was hired to fix a bunch of stuff from someone else's previous development, so I didn't write much of the code on the site and the site's on a winery cms that loves to throw in all kinds of css that I inevitably have to override, so that was making it tough. I appreciate your effort to root out the problem.